# regex command to remove word wrap in cells of .csv file

Tags: regex, notepad

i have a .csv file that contains word wraps in some its cells (which makes it difficult to further work with the file). for example:

```
"......;"Test 
File";......."
```

i hope it's clear what i mean. Is there a way to remove the word wrap with a regex command? So that the cell in the .csv file would look like this instead:

`"......;"Test File";......."`

Comment: What have you tried? Aren't you just removing new line characters (`[\r\n]`)?

Comment: I have been dealing with this regularly. Check the format of the first field. If the line does not start with it, remove the linebreak, this is how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `\n(?!")`
Replace with    (1 space)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k1VUY9/2)

Assuming that each line in the file starts with a `"`, this regex looks for a new line that doesn't start with `"` and replaces with 1 space.

Comment: this one is even better because each line indeed starts with a ". One problem i discovered though, aparently the words at the end of the line and at the start of the new line don't have a space between them. So in other words i get: ""......;"TestFile";......." after using your command. Maybe you can help me with this!?

Answer (score 0):

Open in notepad++ and turn on show all characters. See what character is shown at the end of the line.

```
LF = \n

CR = \r

CRLF = \r\n
```

Then you will need to identify what a pattern of what should be merged into one line and what shouldn't. The best way that I know of is to look for lowercase letters that follow a line break, such as this:

```
Search: \r\n(\l)
Replace: $1
```

But you will need to go through afterwards to validate what has been done.

Hopefully there is a pattern of some kind in your file. Maybe the second line has no tabs or commas?

Comment: i tried this and it shows this "CRLF" after EVERY line (including the wrong ones). the problem is i only want to replace the ones i mentioned above. In other words i probably need to search for all word wraps followed by any type of letter or something like that

Comment: OK then you will need to identify a pattern of some kind that shows what should be merged into one line and what shouldn't.